# Firebase Ads SDK 11.2.0 compile SDK

Tags: android, firebase, admob

I have released recently an app, in which I used firebase-ads: 11.2.0 library. The app was compiled against API 25 (target 23) But today I read in Admob release notes 11.2.0:

> When you upgrade your app to version 11.2.0 or later of the Google Mobile Ads SDK, your app's build.gradle must also be updated to specify acompileSdkVersion of at least 26 (Android O). This does not change the way your app runs. You will not be required to update targetSdkVersion.

I tested it and ads are working on all devices. Do I really need to change compile SDK version to 26? (I had no compile errors). May it not work on incoming Android O devices?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you need to change compile SDK version to 26 because the version of ads is for android O so I don't think it will work on android O devices